# collapse already repeated sectiosn when adding new repeated sections using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a data entry form created using javascript and asp.net with repeated sections . There is  a button created to append new repeated sections .I want to collapse the previous repeated sections while adding the new one.

Comment: Please provide us some code maybe JSFiddle example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Unfxn/27/                                                                                                    refer the above fiddle and i would like to collapse the previously added new fight while adding a new fight

Comment: It works fine for me, when I click on delete button the section is deleted/collapsed perfectly.

Comment: You need to add delete function logic into separate function and use it twice, first time when the new section is created (inside the `$('.addFight').click(...`) and the second time in `$('.deleteFight').click(...` function.

Comment: i would like to have the div collapsed whenever i add new elements after the first one